# inserting sql query into text file via batch throws unexpected text error

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to loop through a list of files and write their names to a separate file. I keep getting an error:

```
values('1' was unexpected at this time.
```

assuming %path% pointed to a folder with the file `MYFILENAME.txt` inside it:

```
rem create file
set cmdfile=%temp%\paullog.sql
CD .>%cmdfile% 

rem loop files and write sql insert commands to file
for %%i in (%path%) DO (
    echo insert into aa..xx([url],[filepath],[invoicenum],[dateUploaded],[SentToHost],[GUID],[twodigitcoid]) values('1','https://aaa.com/xcc17%2Freceipt34%2F%%~nxi',null,getdate(),1,newid(),'00'); >> %cmdfile% 
    rem move "%%i" "%savepath%\%hhmmss%_%%~nxi"
)
```

output goal file should contain (the %2F is not a mistake it is desired):

`insert into aa..xx([url],[filepath],[invoicenum],[dateUploaded],[SentToHost],[GUID],[twodigitcoid]) values('1','https://aaa.com/xcc17%2Freceipt34%2FMYFILENAME.txt',null,getdate(),1,newid(),'00');`

Ive tried:

- put quotes around the whole string to be inserted, but this didn't work because the output in the file had quotes
- escaping the %2F (which is wanted) by using ^%2F but this didnt help

Comment: Are you sure you mean `bash` and not batch?

Comment: @mashuptwice whoops.... this is why I should never post without enough coffee. typo fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the parentheses were causing an issue, so I escaped them using `^`, which means the echo line is now:

`echo insert into aa..xx^([url],[filepath],[invoicenum],[dateUploaded],[SentToHost],[GUID],[twodigitcoid]^) values^('1','https://aaa.com/xcc17%2Freceipt34%2F%%~nxi',null,getdate^(^),1,newid^(^),'00'^); >> %cmdfile%`